# How to detect mouse event on svg?

Tags: svg

I have map look like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="rootMap" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" zoomAndPan="disable" viewBox="0 0 327 273">
<style>
    path, rect{fill: #fff;stroke: #000;cursor: crosshair;}      
</style>
<script>
    function test(evt){
        alert(evt.target.id);
    }
</script>   
<svg x="0" y="0" onclick="test(evt)" width="327" height="273" viewBox="596302 -1188413 45 38">
    <g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <rect x="596302" y="-1188413" width="30" height="30" id="2"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
<svg x="0" y="0" onclick="test(evt)" width="327" height="273" viewBox="50000 -600000 327 273">
    <g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <rect x="50000" y="-600000" width="100" height="50" id="1"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I expect when any rect is clicked, function test will be called. But when click on rect#1 is true, rect#2 was not called. why?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, rect#1 is on top of rect#2. When clicking on a point where two or more elements overlap, the onclick handler is only called for the top most element. This makes sense because the top most element is covering (i.e. hiding) the other element(s).